# Call solidity function from JavaScript got [object promise]?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a very simple Solidity function in a contract `MyContract`.

```
function getCount() view public returns (uint) {
    return myArray.length;
}
```

And the following JavaScript which uses web3 prints `[object Promise]` instead of the count number?

```
MyContract.deployed().then(i => {
  var count = i.getCount.call();
  console.log(count); // print [object Promise]
})
```

Comment: It seems like getCount.call() returns a promise - either await it or use .then(), like you did one step above.

Comment: What is the `deployed` method? Did you mean `deploy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code:

```
MyContract.deployed().then(i => {
  var count = i.getCount.call();
  console.log(count); // print [object Promise]
})
```

MyContract.deployed() will deploy contract to eth network. It will take time to miners verify and add contract code to blockchain. After successful completion of this process then() will invoke.

And coming to i is deployed  contract object, using `i variable`  you can access contract.

```
i.getCount.call().then(val =>{ console.log("Value")}) //instance.getCount().call will returns promise. So
```

call() is async method i.e it will not wait for complete the step. When you got the data at that time then() will invoke.

Or simply call `instance.getCount()` your execution will pause until you get the result.

My option is use then()